# How can I reload pserve when a template changes?

Tags: python, pyramid, pyinotify

I have pserve --reload working with any python changes, but I still have to manually reload when I change a template.

I made this little script that monitors my templates folder for any changes, but what is the command to reload pserve? If I need to call a pserve method from within my Pyramids project, like in **init**.py or something, what is the method I would call to reload pserve?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pyinotify
from subprocess import call
import time

wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
mask = pyinotify.IN_DELETE | pyinotify.IN_CREATE | pyinotify.IN_MODIFY

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):
        print "Modified: ", event.pathname

        # This is where my reload call would go...            
        # call(["pserve", "reload"])

handler = EventHandler()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)
wdd = wm.add_watch("/path/to/my/pyramid/templates/", mask, rec=True, auto_add=True)

notifier.loop()
```

Comment: add code showing how you setup you jinja2 pyramid environment into pyramid Configurator object (your_project.__init__.py and a sample *.ini PasteDeploy file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pyramid already provides a method to reload templates without restarting `pserve` by putting such configuration in a PasteDeploy `development.ini` file or using environment variables.  See [Environment Variables and .ini File Settings](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html).  Of course, do not enable template reloading in production as it slows down your application.

Comment: Weird. I have pyramid.reload_templates set to true, but when I make changes to my jinja2 templates pserve doesn't reload. Looks like it should according to this: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-jinja2/en/latest/

Comment: pserve won't reload the entire process when a template is changed; it's only necessary to do this when a Python file is changed.  However, if pyramid.reload_templates is true, the changes you make to the file will be reflected immediately.

Comment: So this didn't actually do the trick in my work environment, but I installed pyramid and jinja2 on a machine at home and it worked. I'll look into the problem more at work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

By the way - nice workaround script. Steve is right, pyramid offers that out-of-the-box. But pyramid built-in watchdog behaviour depends also on your configuration. [Including pyramid_jinja2](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-jinja2/en/latest/index.html#setup) into your pyramid project triggers a lot of stuff in pyramid and makes some assumptions about template file extensions (*.jinja2) as well.

pyramid_jinja offers configuration for template reloading - it can be [enabled](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-jinja2/en/latest/index.html#pyramid-reload-templates)/disabled as well. Since pyramid 1.5 (do you use it?) you can use setting `pyramid.reload_templates' as well.

But the best thing you can do is to [try the pyramid scaffold that uses jinja2 templates](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-jinja2/en/latest/index.html#creating-a-jinja2-pyramid-project). Takes you 5 minutes to setup, then you change a jinja2 template and see if pyramid is reloading or not. If pyramid is reloading, what I expect, you can continue to debug the problem with your current application.

Comment: Excellent input. Thank you very much. It gives me something to dig into deeper.

I installed pyramid_jinja2, but never ran the setup.py for it. I just updated my development.ini and MINIFEST.in files so I could use the jinja2 templates. I will run the setup.py on Monday and compare the differences.

On Monday I will mark one of these as "answered".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set your config object to take in the settings from the development.ini as well. Something like config = Configurator(settings = settings)